# Programmatic equivalent of an android XML snippet

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anybody mention the programmatic equivalent of below XML code (for use it in android activity transition animation)

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/> 
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" /> 
</set>
```

Comment: And what's the result of your own attempt at translation? Where is it failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this help you.

```
    final AnimationSet showanim = new AnimationSet( true );
    Animation trans = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 0, 100, 0); 
    trans.setDuration( 5000 );
    showanim.addAnimation( trans );
```

And then add it to your ui element. For example if you use TextView then use

```
yourtext.setAnimation(showanim);
```